# Trying to Copy rows selected with checkboxes to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am a bit stuck: I have the below code for a spreadsheet which copies rows, selected with a checkbox, into a second sheet.

I now need to amend this code so that the copied rows are pasted into another workbook on a specific sheet.

I have tried `Workbooks("").Worksheets("")` and also using the whole C drive path but always get a run-time 9, subscript out of range error. I haven't had any luck in finding a solution online.

Both workbooks are saved on my desktop currently for ease:

```vb
Sub CopyRows()

For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
        For r = 1 To Rows.Count
            If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                    LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Range("A" & LRow & ":R" & LRow) = _
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r & ":R" & r).Value
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This recorded macro takes the data to where it needs to go:

```
Sub Transfer()
'
' Transfer Macro
'

'
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E7:E8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("M2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("G2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("N2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E13").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("S2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("J2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E16").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("I2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E17").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("C2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E20").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
    Range("D2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Destination.xls").Activate
    Range("E21").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("WIP - Live.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Code with error at destination workbook:

```
Sub CopyRows()

For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
        For r = 1 To Rows.Count
            If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                With Workbooks("Destination").Sheets("Sheet2")
                    LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Range("A" & LRow & ":R" & LRow) = _
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r & ":R" & r).Value
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Solved: I have managed to get it working with the below code:

```
Sub CopyRows()

For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
        For r = 1 To Rows.Count
            If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                With Workbooks("Destination.xlsm").Sheets("Details")
                    LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Range("A" & LRow & ":U" & LRow) = _
                    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & r & ":U" & r).Value
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The error was being caused by the Sheet 2 name in the destination workbook. I had to amend the name to details and it started working. Frustratingly simple for how long I spent on it!

Many Thanks to ed2 and norie for the replies and help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090746/excel-vba-copy-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-workbook?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yeh that syntax for locating the destination workbook is giving me the error. I could record the macro in the same way but then I lose the ability to select which row I want to copy with the checkboxes.

Comment: Record it anyway, post the code it records, and let's have a look.

Comment: @ed2 Updated with recorded macro.

Comment: @Worldbound Can you post the amended code that's causing the error(s)?

Comment: Have you tried adding the appropriate file extension for the destination workbook? P.S. Don't post code in a comment - edit the original question and add it there.

Comment: @norie Ah ok, thanks for the heads up. I have saved the document as macro enabled and amended the extension in the code accordingly but there was no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. First:
   Change

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r & ":R" & r).Value
```

to

```
Workbooks("WIP - Live.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r & ":R" & r).Value
```

2. Then:
   Change

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

to

```
Workbooks("Destination.xls").Sheets("Sheet2")
```

This assumes that both workbooks are already open when the macro is run. If not, you will need code to open one or both of them.

Comment: Gave it a go, no luck. I am getting the error on the `With Workbooks("Destination.xls").Sheets("Sheet2")` line.